# DataColumn into list (same datatype)

Tags: c#, .net, list

How can i convert a DataColumn into a list of values with the same datatype as the column?

Example:

```
  static List<T> ColumnValuesToList<T>(DataTable dt,out string typeName)
         {
             typeName = dt.Columns[0].DataType.ToString();
             List<T> list = new List<T>();
             foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
             {
              // var value = row[0];
              //list.Add(value);
                list.Add(row[0]);
             }
             return list;
        }
```

Calling:

```
    List<int> myList = ColumnValuesToList(myDtWithInts,typeInfo);
    List<string> myList = ColumnValuesToList(myDtWithStrings,typeInfo);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to get the value from the DataRow in the right *type*. I.e., you can either *cast*:

```
list.Add((T)row[0]);
```

or (which I would prefer) use the [`Field<T>` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has the advantage of working correctly with nullable types (`DBNull.Value` is automatically converted to `null`):

```
list.Add(row.Field<T>(0));
```

However, using LINQ, you don't really need to implement this yourself:

```
List<int> myList = myDtWithInts.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(drow => drow.Field<int>(0)).ToList();
```